# Insert line number in all files in folder

Tags: linux, console

I have folder which contains more then 100 files. I want to insert line number into each file.

`nl` command gives output to standard output on terminal. But I want to add line number in all files of folder.

Can you suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Quick suggestions: preview your question to make sure it will appear as you want it to. Currently, it displays text as "code" which is actually not code. Do not request answers or sign your messages - if you post a question, it is implicit that you want it answered; and your username should be enough to identify you.

Answer (score 1):

Following on @Gianluca's answer, and using `bash` instead:

```
for i in *.c *.h ; do ( nl $i > $i.numbered ) && mv $i.numbered $i ; done
```

This replaces all files ending with .c or .h in the current directory with line-numbered versions.

Answer (score 0):

Using tcsh you can do something like

```
foreach f (`ls *`)
nl $f >> $f.out
mv $f.out $f
end
```

You can delete them `mv` command if you don't want to rename the files
(try the script on a copy ;-) )